# codeigniter 4 routes query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is my function

```
public function check()
{   
    $data = [
                'pageTitle' => 'Documents Check',
                'action' => 'check',
                'validation' => NULL,
    ];
    
    if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){

        $validation = $this->validate([
            'jobNo' => [
                        'rules' => 'required|numeric|exact_length[6]|is_not_unique[docs.Job_no]',
                        'errors' => [
                               'required' => 'Job No. required.',
                               'exact_length' => 'Job No. should be exactly 6 digits.',
                               'numeric' => 'Job No. should be numbers only.',
                               'is_not_unique' => 'No files available for entered Job No.',
                           ]    
                      ],
        ]);
        if($validation){
            $jobNo = $this->request->getVar('jobNo',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $data['docs'] = $this->docsModel->getDocsByJob($jobNo);
            return view('documents/files_display',$data);
        }
        else{
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator; 
        }  
        
    } // post

   return view('documents/files_view',$data);
} // check
```

file_display looks

| id | Job No | Document | action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23233 | invoice.pdf | remove |
| 2 | 23233 | deliver.pdf | remove |

```
public function remove($id){        
    if($this->docsModel->delete($id);){
            return redirect()->back()->with('success','file removed from the Job record');
        }
}
```

so here redirect()->back() or current_url() takes me to the page where i have to again enter the "Job No" on a form. What i was looking for was to stay on file_display page on clicking the remove.

Comment: "I want" isn't a question. Please show some relevant code and explain exactly where you're stuck with trying to achieve what you want. See also [ask] and the [tour] for more guidance on asking a useful, answerable question.

Comment: The best we can tell you right now is "if you want to do a redirect, then write code to do a redirect in the appropriate place". Since we can't see anything about your code, or understand what difficulty you might be having in making a redirect, we probably can't usefully say much more, other than perhaps guessing at some appropriate code. But it's better to be able to  write an accurate answer based on the reality of your situation. Thanks.

Comment: `What i was looking for was to stay on file_display page on clicking the remove.`...why not redirect to the file display page instead then? Or you could use AJAX for the remove() action so there's no postback to begin with

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can using [Session](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

```
public function check()
{   
    $data = [
                'pageTitle' => 'Documents Check',
                'action' => 'check',
                'validation' => NULL,
    ];
    
    if($this->request->getMethod() == 'post'){

        $validation = $this->validate([
            'jobNo' => [
                        'rules' => 'required|numeric|exact_length[6]|is_not_unique[docs.Job_no]',
                        'errors' => [
                               'required' => 'Job No. required.',
                               'exact_length' => 'Job No. should be exactly 6 digits.',
                               'numeric' => 'Job No. should be numbers only.',
                               'is_not_unique' => 'No files available for entered Job No.',
                           ]    
                      ],
        ]);
        if($validation){
            $jobNo = $this->request->getVar('jobNo',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $data['docs'] = $this->docsModel->getDocsByJob($jobNo);
            
            //Save jobNo to SESSION
            session()->set('jobNo', $jobNo);
            
            return view('documents/files_display',$data);
        }
        else{
            $data['validation'] = $this->validator; 
        }  
        
    } // post

   // Add GET method condition, and if there is jobNo in session
   if($this->request->getMethod() == 'get' && session->has('jobNo')){
       $jobNo = session()->get('jobNo');
       $data['docs'] = $this->docsModel->getDocsByJob($jobNo);
       return view('documents/files_display',$data);
   }

   // Remove Session when accessing FORM (Optional)
   // session()->remove('jobNo');
   
   return view('documents/files_view',$data);
} // check
```